# MaskedEditText hint криво работает

Tags: android, xml

Я использую [maskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) библиотеку. У меня есть xml

```
 <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
                        android:id="@+id/phoneSend"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="(111) 111 11 11"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        mask:mask="(###) ###-##-##"
                    >
                    </br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText>
```

Xml содержит `hint`. Если я ввожу строку вида: `1234` то она вводится как `2341`, т.е первый символ уходит в конец. Но если я убираю `hint` все работает хорошо. Но мне нужно использовать `hint`, подскажите пожалуйста почему с `hint` первый символ уходит в конец.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел в библиотеке метод :

```
private int lastValidPosition() {
        if(rawText.length() == maxRawLength) {
            return rawToMask[rawText.length() - 1] + 1;
        }
        return nextValidPosition(rawToMask[rawText.length()]);
    }
```

Грешу на него из-за вот этой строки :

```
return rawToMask[rawText.length() - 1] + 1;
```

Советую еще раз пересмотреть библиотеку, лучше разобраться как она работает.